# Bounty- User puts 50+ bounty but gives 25+

Tags: discussion, bounty

I answered a question ([Is there a limit on pinned taskbar items?](https://superuser.com/questions/947525/is-there-a-limit-on-pinned-taskbar-items/993650#993650)) Which the user put a bounty of 50+ reputation. After the grace period ended, I was rewarded, but only 25+. Is this normal behavior? Can I do this on any bounty, or does the bounty automatically decrease after the grace period is ended ? (I answered before the grace period.)

Comment: The bounty expired without being awarded.  As you had a score of +2 then half the bounty was awarded to you. http://superuser.com/help/bounty

Comment: The user didn't assign the bounty manually, so half of the bounty it was automatically awarded to you as your answer was the highest-scoring new answer. See the linked question for more information.

Comment: @bwDraco, Where does the other half go to?

Comment: The other half of the bounty is forfeited.